# JBehave - serial execution across GivenStories

Tags: jbehave

I am using JBehave - I have three stories - third story refers other two stories:

GivenStories Story1, Story2

Given Some_Thing
When you_compare_output_of_story_1_to_output_of_story_2
Then verify_the_result

When I run this third story - expectation is to run the

first scenario of 1st story
first scenario of 2nd story
then the scenario in 3rd story

--

second scenario of 1st story
second scenario of 2nd story
then the scenario in 3rd story

but JBehave runs all the scenarios in the 1st story, then all the scenarios in the 2nd story ..:(

I am not finding a way to get it the way I am looking for. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try using jbehave version 4.3 which has fix provided

Answer (score 0):

Read about [GivenStories filtered by scenario meta parameters](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/given-stories.html)

The idea is that you use `meta tags` in the first and second stories, like in below examples:
**First story**

```
First story

Scenario: scenario 1
Meta: @id1 scenario1

Given Story 1 scenario 1
..........


Scenario: scenario 2
Meta: @id1 scenario2

Given Story 1 scenario 2
..........

Scenario: scenario 3
Meta: @id1 scenario3

Given Story 1 scenario 3
..........
```

**Second story**

```
Second story

Scenario: scenario 1
Meta: @id1 scenario1

Given Story 2 scenario 1
..........


Scenario: scenario 2
Meta: @id1 scenario2

Given Story 2 scenario 2
..........

Scenario: scenario 3
Meta: @id1 scenario3

Given Story 2 scenario 3
..........
```

and **in the third story you need to filter them using these meta tags**:

```
Third story

Scenario: scenario 1
GivenStories: path/to/stories/first_story.story#{id1:scenario1},
              path/to/stories/second_story.story#{id1:scenario1}

Given Story 3 scenario 1
..........

Scenario: scenario 2
GivenStories: path/to/stories/first_story.story#{id1:scenario2},
              path/to/stories/second_story.story#{id1:scenario2}

Given Story 3 scenario 2
..........


Scenario: scenario 3
GivenStories: path/to/stories/first_story.story#{id1:scenario3},
              path/to/stories/second_story.story#{id1:scenario3}

Given Story 3 scenario 3
..........
```

Comment: I tried but is not working! I am using 3.8, will that be an issue?

Comment: Yes, this has been fixed in 3.9.1 --> http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JBEHAVE-789

Comment: Updated to 3.9.1 but it is still not working - whenever there is a meta @id in the givenstories, the steps in the 3rd story are not getting executed!